# Role-Based Security in Windows desktop and web application

Tags: .net, role-based-access-control

I have been tasked with researching role-based security technology for possible inclusion in our .Net based desktop and web applications. I envision sending a service the security credentials of the application user and receiving back a configuration stream describing what UI elements to present to the user. Any ideas of which open-source or commercial technologies will do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open ended recommendation requests are not really what this site is for, and will generally not get you a properly useful answer. Consider OAuth, SAML, SSO, WIF... which of these have you looked at and do you have a specific question for one them in regards to your problem?

Comment: Those are all authorization technologies not RBS. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Of Authentication (who you say you are - SAML, WIF) and Authorization (what you are permitted to do - OAuth), role based security is Authorization - what you are permitted to do.

Comment: I think they are all technologies an RBS would wrap itself around.

Comment: You can and should wrap them for your own application's needs, but its only a naming difference at that point.

Comment: Apache Shiro is closest to what I am looking for. Thanks for responding.